# phonegap connect to a php on a server

Tags: php, android, jquery, cordova

Hello I am doing an App that get some information and trys to connect to php located on a server.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PhoneGap</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click( function() {
        alert('hello hello');

        $.ajax({
            url: "192.168.0.106/test/testget.php",        
            data: {
                t:"lalalala"
            },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (status)
            {
                if (status.success == false)
                {
                    alert("Failure!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Success!");
                }
            }
        });

    });
    });
</script>


 </head>
 <body style="background: url(BG.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: 100%;" onload="onBodyLoad()">
<button style="background-color:grey;margin-left:75%;display:block;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:0%" type="button" onclick="alert('Formulario Enviado')">Enviar</button> 

 <u><h3>TAREA (MOLINO 3)</h3></u> 
  <div style="height:378px;width:305px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
<form> 
<table border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>Verificación de banda transportadora</th>
 <th>OK</th>
 <th>NO</th>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td>Fugas del material y estado de los rodillos.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB1"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Desalineamiento de la cinta o banda.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB2"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>La superficie de la banda.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB3"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El ajuste de la guarda.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB4"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El ajuste del rascador.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB5" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB5" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>La temperatura del motor.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB6"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>La vibración de la banda.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB7"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El sensor de movimiento.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB8"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB8"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El funcionamiento de las paradas de emergencia.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB9" ></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El estado del tambor de cola.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB10"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El revestimiento del tambor motriz.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB11" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB11" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Los ruidos anormales en el equipo.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB12" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB12" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>La lubricación del tambor de la chumacera.</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB13"></td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="DB13"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Las fugas del lubricante.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB14" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB14" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El estado de las luminarias en la zona (luminarias rotas y funcionales).</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB15" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB15" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El material centrado en la cinta.</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB16" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB16" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El material que está por debajo de la banda (apartarlo).</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB17" ></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="DB17" ></td>
</tr>
<th align="center">Comentarios</th>
 </tr>
    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="20">
</textarea>
    </td>
</div>
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="pressme">
</form>
</table>

<br>


 </body>
</html>
```

The php file located at: **192.168.0.106/test/testget.php** contains:

```
<?php echo $_GET['t'] ?>
```

The thing with all this is not the part of the connection is that I don't get the message over the script

**UPDATE:**
 The problem was located at the phone gap not getting the right plugins to work.

**UPDATE 2:**
MAKE SURE you are using the right jquery files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check this things:

#### 1. Add error callback (or fail if you are using jQuery version 1.8 +) to your ajax call, just like success:

```
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again - error:' + error);
    }
```

#### 2. Handle different status codes with statusCode postback:

```
    statusCode: {
        400: function() {
            alert("Bad request!");
        },
        401: function() {
            alert("Unauthorized!");
        },
        403: function() {
            alert("Forbidden!");
        },
        404: function() {
            alert("Page not found!");
        },                
        408: function() {
            alert("Request Timeout!");
        },
        200: function() {
            alert("page reached");
        },    
    }
```

If there's an error you will probably get some of this codes.

#### 3. If you haven't add this line into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It will allow you to access an internet and your local network

#### 4. If you are testing this on a real mobile phone

Don't forget to turn your WIFI or 3G on. You would be amazed how many people forget to do this.

#### 5. Check that your server accepts outside requests

This may sound stupid but some Windows *AMP solutions need to be put online before you can access them from the network. One of them is for example WAMP.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer the problem was located on the phonegap plugins not loading on the last build we fix it and we manage to get the connection

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
type: 'GET'
```

Example :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: postData+'&amp;lid='+landmarkID,
            url: 'http://your-domain.com/comments/save.php',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Your comment was successfully added');
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error adding your comment');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be GET variable - use

```
datatype: "text"
```

instead of

```
datatype: "json"
```

Otherwise to get the message you must parse JSON in your PHP script

Comment: I did try it and change it but no alert pop up or anything